# How to get formatted date time in python

Tags: python, linux

I want my Linux Filename like this

```
May-01-0340AM-2011.tar
```

How can i get the date variable formatted like above in Python

IN bash i write

```
date1=$(date +"%b-%d-%I%M%p-%G")
```

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You can use the same formatting string in [`strftime`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.date.strftime) on a [`datetime` object](http://docs.python.org/library/datetime.html#datetime-datetime):

```
>>> import datetime
>>> datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%b-%d-%I%M%p-%G')
'May-16-0245PM-2011'
```

Incidentally, I'd just like to put a word in for the joy of [ISO-8601 date formatting](http://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/%7Emgk25/iso-time.html)

Comment: +1: You clearly beat me by five minutes according to the timestamp :-)

Answer (score 7):

Same formatting, using [`strftime()`](http://docs.python.org/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior):

```
>>> import datetime
>>> datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%b-%d-%I%M%p-%G')
'May-16-1050PM-2011'
```

To get your filename, it's as simple as:

```
 >>> datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%b-%d-%I%M%p-%G') + '.tar'
'May-16-1050PM-2011.tar'
```